# Exercise 3.F.5 in "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

> 3.94 **Definition** ***dual space***, $V'$
> The ***dual space*** of $V$, denoted $V'$, is the vector space of all linear functionals on $V$. In other words, $V'=\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{F})$.

> Exercise 3.F.5
> Suppose $V_1,\dots,V_m$ are vector spaces. Prove that $(V_1\times\dots\times V_m)'$ and $V_{1}^{'}\times\dots\times V_{m}^{'}$ are isomorphic vector spaces.

If $V_1,\dots,V_m$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, then I can prove that $(V_1\times\dots\times V_m)'$ and $V_{1}^{'}\times\dots\times V_{m}^{'}$ are isomorphic vector spaces as follows:

> My proof:
> By 3.95 on p.101, $V_{1}^{'},\dots,V_{m}^{'}$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces and $\dim V_1=\dim V_{1}^{'},\dots,\dim V_m=\dim V_{m}^{'}$ hold.
> By 3.76 on p.92, $V_1\times\dots\times V_m$ and $V_{1}^{'}\times\dots\times V_{m}^{'}$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces and $\dim(V_1\times\dots\times V_m)=\dim V_1+\dots+\dim V_m$ and $\dim(V_{1}^{'}\times\dots\times V_{m}^{'})=\dim V_{1}^{'}+\dots+\dim V_{m}^{'}$ hold.
> By 3.95 on p.101, $(V_1\times\dots\times V_m)^{'}$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $\dim (V_1\times\dots\times V_m)=\dim (V_1\times\dots\times V_m)^{'}$ holds.
> So, $\dim (V_1\times\dots\times V_m)^{'}=\dim (V_1\times\dots\times V_m)=\dim V_1+\dots+\dim V_m=\dim V_{1}^{'}+\dots+\dim V_{m}^{'}=\dim(V_{1}^{'}\times\dots\times V_{m}^{'})$.
> By 3.59 on p.82, $(V_1\times\dots\times V_m)'$ and $V_{1}^{'}\times\dots\times V_{m}^{'}$ are isomorphic vector spaces.

Comment: Hint : try to find an explicit linear isomorphism $V_1'\times \ldots\times V_m' \to (V_1\times \ldots V_m)'$.

Comment: what does the notation $(\quad)'$ stand for?

Comment: @SolubleFish Thank you very much for your hint.

Comment: @AlexeyKubanov Thank you very much for your comment. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i\in \{1,\ldots,m\}$, let $p_i:V_1\times \ldots \times V_m \to V_i$ be the canonical linear surjections and $\iota_i:V_i\to V_1 \times \ldots \times V_m$ the canonical linear injections. We know that $p_i\circ \iota_j = 0$ if $i\neq j$ and $\rm{id}_{V_i}$ if $i=j$ and that :
$$\rm{id}_{V_1\times\ldots\times V_m} = \sum_{i=1}^m \iota_i\circ p_i$$

Define a map $\Phi : V_1'\times \ldots \times V_m' \to (V_1\times \ldots \times V_m)'$ by the formula :

$$\forall f_1\in V_1', \ldots , f_m\in V_m',\Phi(f_1,\ldots,f_m) =\sum_{i=1}^m f_i\circ p_i$$

This does define a linear map, let us show that it is an isomorphism.

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ such that $\Phi(f_1,\ldots,f_m) = 0$. Then, for $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$, we have :
\begin{align}
0 &= \Phi(f_1,\ldots,f_m)\circ \iota_i \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^m f_j\circ p_j\circ \iota_i \\
&= f_i
\end{align}
Therefore $(f_1,\ldots,f_m) = 0$ and we see that $\Phi$ is injective.

Let $g\in (V_1\times \ldots \times V_m)'$ . For $i\in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ let $f_i = g\circ\iota_i \in V_i'$.

Then, we can compute :
\begin{align}
g &= g\circ\left(\sum_{i=1}^m \iota_i\circ p_i\right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m g\circ \iota_i\circ p_i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m f_i\circ p_i \\
&= \Phi(f_1,\ldots,f_m)
\end{align}

Therefore $\Phi$ is surjective.

Comment: SolubleFish, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: How would you define a canonical linear injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$? Would it be something like $x \mapsto (1,1,…,x,..,1)$?

Comment: Almost : for this to be a linear map, you need zeros instead of ones.

Answer (score 0):

SolubleFish, Thank you very much for your hint.

Let $\varphi_1\in V_{1}^{'},\dots,\varphi_m\in V_{m}^{'}$.
Define $f: V_{1}^{'}\times\dots\times V_{m}^{'}\to(V_1\times\dots\times V_m)^{'}$ as follows:
$f(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m)(v_1,\dots,v_m):=\varphi_1(v_1)+\dots+\varphi_m(v_m)$.
Then, it is easy to verify that $f(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m)\in (V_1\times\dots\times V_m)^{'}$.

Let $V_{1}^{'}\times\dots\times V_{m}^{'}\ni(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m)\neq (\varphi_{1}^{'},\dots,\varphi_{m}^{'})\in V_{1}^{'}\times\dots\times V_{m}^{'}$.
Then, there exists $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ such that $\varphi_i\neq\varphi_{i}^{'}$.
Then, there exists $v_i\in V_i$ such that $\varphi_i(v_i)\neq\varphi_{i}^{'}(v_i)$.
Then, $f(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m)(0,\dots,0,v_i,0,\dots,0)=\varphi_i(v_i)\neq\varphi_{i}^{'}(v_i)=f(\varphi_{1}^{'},\dots,\varphi_{m}^{'})(0,\dots,0,v_i,0,\dots,0).$
So, $f(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m)\neq f(\varphi_{1}^{'},\dots,\varphi_{m}^{'})$.
So, $f$ is injective.

Let $\Phi\in (V_1\times\dots\times V_m)^{'}$.
Let $\varphi_1(v_1):=\Phi(v_1,0,\dots,0)$.
$\dots$
Let $\varphi_i(v_i):=\Phi(0,\dots,0,v_i,0,\dots,0)$.
$\dots$
Let $\varphi_m(v_m):=\Phi(0,\dots,v_m)$.
Then, $\varphi_1\in V_{1}^{'},\dots,\varphi_m\in V_{m}^{'}$.
And $f(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m)(v_1,\dots,v_m)=\Phi(v_1,0,\dots,0)+\dots+\Phi(0,\dots,0,v_m)=\Phi(v_1,\dots,v_m)$.
So, $f$ is surjective.

Let $(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m),(\varphi_{1}^{'},\dots,\varphi_{m}^{'})\in V_{1}^{'}\times\dots\times V_{m}^{'}$.
Then,
$f(\varphi_1+\varphi_{1}^{'},\dots,\varphi_m+\varphi_{m}^{'})(v_1,\dots,v_m)=(\varphi_1+\varphi_{1}^{'})(v_1)+\dots+(\varphi_m+\varphi_{m}^{'})(v_m)=(\varphi_1(v_1)+\dots+\varphi_m(v_m))+(\varphi_{1}^{'}(v_1)+\dots+\varphi_{m}^{'}(v_m))=f(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m)(v_1,\dots,v_m)+f(\varphi_{1}^{'},\dots,\varphi_{m}^{'})(v_1,\dots,v_m)=(f(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m)+f(\varphi_{1}^{'},\dots,\varphi_{m}^{'}))(v_1,\dots,v_m).$
And
$f(c\varphi_1,\dots,c\varphi_m)(v_1,\dots,v_m)=c\varphi_1(v_1)+\dots+c\varphi_m(v_m)=c(\varphi_1(v_1)+\dots+\varphi_m(v_m))=cf(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m)(v_1,\dots,v_m)=(cf(\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m))(v_1,\dots,v_m).$
So, $f$ is a linear map.